# Find three positive numbers x,y,z such that their sum is 30 and P=xzy^2 is maximal.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I tried do this question by equating p to xyz, thus getting y = 1 and x,z = 14.5. I'm pretty sure this method is wrong however. Any idea how the P=xzy^2 comes into play?

I understand the method when the product is simply xyz.

Comment: Hint: Lagrange multipliers works well here.

Answer (score 2):

By the AM-GM inequality,
$$30=x+z+\frac{y}{2}+\frac{y}{2}\geq 4\cdot\left(\frac{xy^2z}{4}\right)^\frac{1}{4}\implies xy^2z\leq 4\cdot\left(\frac{15}{2}\right)^4$$ The equality holds when $x = \frac{y}{2} = z = \frac{15}{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a soul crushing approach with partial derivatives:$$x+y+z = 30,\quad x,y,z>0$$

We wish to maximise $$P:= xzy^2$$

$x=30-y-z$

Then $P=(30-y-z)\cdot zy^2 = 30zy^2-zy^3-z^2y^2$

We must find the critical points i.e. $\frac{\partial P}{\partial z}=\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=0$

$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial z}= 30y^2 -y^3-2zy^2 =0$$

$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = 60zy-3zy^2-2z^2y=0$$

$y^2(30-y-2z)=0\implies y=0$ or $y=2z-30$

$zy(60-3y-2z)=0\implies y=0$ or $z=0$ or $y=\frac{60-2z}{3}$

Now note that  $y,z\neq 0$

$y=2z-30 \implies 60z(2z-30)-3z(2z-30)^2-2z^2(2z-30)=0 $

$\implies -4z(4z^2-135z+1125)=0\implies z=15$ or $z=\frac{75}{4}$

$z=15 \implies y=0$ so we ignore this point since $y>0$

$z=\frac{75}{4} \implies y=\frac{15}{2}$

Also note that $30(\frac{60-2z}{3})^2-(\frac{60-2z}{3})^3-2z(\frac{60-2z}{3})^2=0$

$\implies \frac{8}{27}(z-30)^2(2z-15)=0\implies z=30$ or $z=\frac{15}{2}$

we reject $z=30$, since we require $x,y>0$. So we also have a stationairy point at $z=\frac{15}{2}, y=15$

Now to classify these points, we must consider the following partial derivatives:

$P_{zz} = -2y^2$

$P_{yy} = 60z-6zy -2z^2$

$P_{zy} = 60y-3y^2-4yz = P_{yz}$

Then we have that at the point $(y,z)=(\frac{15}{2},\frac{75}{4})$

$P_{yy}P_{zz}-P_{yz}^2 = -\frac{253125}{8}<0$ which means it is a saddle point

At $(y,z) = (15,\frac{15}{2})$, we have:

$P_{yy}P_{zz}-P_{yz}^2 = 101250>0$ so this is a maximum or a minimum

Since $P_{yy} =-\frac{675}{2}<0$ and $P_{zz} =-\frac{225}{2} <0$ at $(15,\frac{15}{2})$, this is a maximum point.

Therefore the maximum of $P$ occurs at $$P(x,y,z) = P(\frac{15}{2},15,\frac{15}{2}) = \frac{50625}{4}$$

Comment: Your answer came when I was posting almost the same  approach ! So, you won (I deleted my answer and upvoted your). Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Well that's kind of you, thanks - did your approach differ in any way? Shame to delete it if it does as it'd be interesting to see if you did it more efficiently than I

Comment: It is normal, don't you think ? I don't see the interest of multiple identical approaches to the same problem. Moreeover, you went further than I did, classifying the points and so on. Good work, for sure.